# AVAssetExportSession estimatedOutputFileLength always returns 0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

Having a problem where the `estimatedOutputFileLength` property of `AVAssetExportSession` always returns **0** (and returns **-9223372036854775808** on the simulator).

I've tried everything to get this to work, trying different `outputFileType`s, toggling `shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse` on and off, specifying (or not specifying) the `outputURL`... despite all this, nothing seems to work and I'm beginning to think this may be a bug in the SDK.

This is my code:

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality]; // doesn't matter which preset is used
//exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
NSLog(@"bytes = %lld", exportSession.estimatedOutputFileLength);
```

I just can't figure out why this isn't working! (iOS 6, iPhone 5)

Comment: Are you confident that you have a good asset?  Please post some log output where you've logged asset.tracks and asset.duration (that's a CMTime).  My guess is that after you do that, you'll want to delete this question and post a new one called "Why is this asset nil?"

Comment: Already tried that...
`AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] options:nil]; NSLog(@"asset track count = %d", asset.tracks.count); NSLog(@"asset duration = %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration));`
Gives me the output:
`[2887:907] asset track count = 2
[2887:907] asset duration = 21.000000`
The asset is good -- it was in fact exported from a previous `AVAssetExportSession` instance itself.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Unfortunately I'm pretty sure it's a bug in iOS 6. Could possible be fixed in iOS 7, but I've not checked. Good luck!

Comment: Same problem in 2014...

Answer (score 8):

You can workaround this problem by setting proper timeRange on the exportSession:

```
exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration);
```

It seems that in iOS, the AVAssetExportSessionInternal.timeRange is not getting sensible result when estimating file length.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the timerange.

How much of the file you intend to export. Without that it will return 0,

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;

CMTime full = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(exporter.asset.duration, 1);
exporter.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, full);
long long size = exporter.estimatedOutputFileLength;
fileInfo.fileSize = size;
```